# Dynamics 2011 OrganizationServiceProxy Authentication

Tags: .net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

We have an installer (vdproj msi) that installs a Dynamics 2011 managed package (a zip file stored as an embedded resource) using the OrganizationServiceProxy. It constructs the OrganizationServiceProxy as follows:

```
var organizationUri = new Uri(string.Format(
  ORGANIZATION_SERVICE_URI_TEMPLATE, configuration.WebServiceUrl, 
  configuration.CrmOrganizationName));

var credentials = new ClientCredentials();
credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = GetNetworkCredentials();

credentials.UserName.UserName = credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName;
credentials.UserName.Password = credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password;

var client = new OrganizationServiceProxy(organizationUri, null, credentials, null)
  { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(WEB_SERVICE_TIMEOUT) };

return client;
```

And executes an ImportSolutionRequest

```
var importSolutionRequest = new ImportSolutionRequest
{
  CustomizationFile = Resources.DynamicsSolution,
  ImportJobId = Guid.NewGuid()
};
service.Execute(importSolutionRequest);
```

This yields the wonderfully obscure error:

> The Web Service plug-in failed in OrganizationId: 510c06a3-6ee9-43a7-ba54-677054348813; SdkMessageProcessingStepId: 1b830950-e106-4ee1-b3fd-d348cb65dc8d; EntityName: none; Stage: 30; MessageName: ImportSolution; AssemblyName: Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin, Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35; ClassName: Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin; Exception: Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>          at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
>          at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
>          at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>          at System.Web.Services.Protocols.LogicalMethodInfo.Invoke(Object target, Object[] values)
>          at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin.Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
>          at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.V5PluginProxyStep.ExecuteInternal(PipelineExecutionContext context)
>          at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.VersionedPluginProxyStepBase.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
>       Inner Exception: System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException: Culture is not supported.
>       Parameter name: culture
>       0 (0x0000) is an invalid culture identifier.
>          at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InitializeFromCultureId(Int32 culture, Boolean useUserOverride)
>          at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.ImportExportPublish.SolutionPackageUpgrade..ctor(ExecutionContext context)
>          at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.ImportExportPublish.RootImportHandler..ctor(ImportXml parent, Boolean overwriteUnmanagedCustomizations, Boolean publishWorkflows, Byte[] compressedCustomizationFile, Boolean setup, Version existingDatabaseVersion, ExecutionContext context, Boolean extractAllFiles)
>          at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.ImportExportPublish.ImportXml..ctor(Boolean overwriteUnmanagedCustomizations, Boolean publishWorkflows, Byte[] compressedCustomizationFile, Guid importJobId, Boolean convertToManaged, ExecutionContext context)
>          at Microsoft.Crm.WebServices.ImportXmlService.ImportSolution(Boolean overwriteUnmanagedCustomizations, Boolean publishWorkflows, Byte[] customizationFile, Guid importJobId, Boolean convertToManaged, ExecutionContext context)

After several hours of research and disassembling Microsoft Dynamics internal dlls (it would be funny if it weren't so sad that I needed to do this), I found that the CallerId in the incoming request's ExecutionContext was empty (even though the request authenticated correctly using the supplied credentials).

So, I looked up the SystemUserId I want to use from the SystemUser table and specified

```
client.CallerId = Guid.Parse("94DB2FFC-DBDE-E011-95D5-005056AF0052");
```

Lo and behold, the ImportSolutionRequest succeeded after doing this.

I'm left with the questions:

1. Is there another way of accomplishing this absurdly basic task without specifying CallerId that actually works? Why doesn't it work without it?
2. If not, how can I get the callerId to set on the OrganizationServiceProxy based on the credentials I supplied (without hard coding it).
3. Why am I having these kinds of problems on a fresh, completely default installation of Dynamics on a brand new server?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with programmatically importing a solution, so I can't answer 1.  For question 2, I think you could use the [WhoAmIRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.whoamirequest.aspx).  As for 3, I'm not sure I'd classify it as a problem until I get an answer to 1.  :)

Comment: The WhoAmIRequest returns a UserId for a hidden user that was apparently automatically created the first time I made the import request...NOT the user I'm authenticating as. It seems that there were two auto created users: SYSTEM, SYSTEM and INTEGRATION, INTEGRATION...and further if I set client.CallerId = whoAmIResponse.UserId, I get the aforementioned error about the culture not being supported. These hidden users do not display in the UI anywhere.

Comment: As for running it programmatically...well Microsoft's own examples of how to do this don't compile, so I'd be surprised if they even know how their API works or have tested it since alpha release...

Comment: IIRC, in CRM 4.0, we would have weird problems with "service account" users (users created just for scheduled tasks or web portal code).  If we didn't log in as the service account at least once to the CRM web UI, the user's UserSettings record wouldn't ever get set up correctly in the db. This would result in strange errors like above (basically a "null" culture). The question is why is WhoAmI returning this "system" user instead of the user running your setup package? Maybe "system" users have null UserSettings as well.

Comment: I verified the usersettingsbase table doesn't have entries for the system/integration accounts (which is where uiculture is)....so any ideas how I can get Dynamics to use the right account?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, but I would concentrate on your credential code.  I believe the NETWORK SERVICE account of the front-end web server logs in as SYSTEM, because if you don't specify a service account for the Async services, it uses NETWORK SERVICE and workflow records show up as created by SYSTEM.  So is this setup package being run by a user directly or is some service or something else running it that is logging in as NETWORK SERVICE?

Comment: It's a web setup vdproj msi. So it should be running as the logged in Domain User (which has admin rights)...but that user isn't even added in Dynamics...and I know it's using the credentials I'm providing to authenticate, because if I change them to something arbitrary, I get an unauthorized exception....so if it's authenticating as the user I'm specifying, why am I showing up logged in as a different one?

Comment: So the user running the setup package is not a user in CRM, but the credentials you are supplying *is* a CRM user, correct?  I think I'd go back to basics and try to build a console app that just connects to your org and creates a contact or something.  It doesn't sound like your problem is around importing; it sounds like you have a lower-level security problem somehow, although your code looks fine to me.

Comment: Correct. I tried that earlier today. Execute requests and such (including creating/updating/deleting entities) work no problem (including from my installer). Plus the stack trace for the error I was getting pertains specifically to importing (Microsoft.Crm.WebServices.ImportXmlService.ImportSolution). Seems like this is a pretty basic, stupid, fundamental bug in Dynamics...unless you have any other thoughts?

Comment: Well, that certainly seems like a bug around ImportSolution then.  Update Rollup 4 was released today, you might try installing that (I saw a few issues around importing solutions but nothing that exactly matched your problem) and then from there you might have to call MS Support...especially if their own SDK examples don't even compile (assuming you are using the latest SDK download). Sorry I couldn't be of more assistance.